# Get posts from pinterest for a specified hashtag

Tags: pinterest, hashtag

How to get the Images from pinterest with a specified hashtag of the pic. I need to get the pinned pictures with a specific hash tags from the pinterest. Is there any way to get.

Comment: No there is not, you cannot even search for it. You have to wait for the public SDK

Comment: @JPHellemons i'm looking for this as well, it is still like this even now ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is a hashtag then no there isn't. If you knew which board it was on, or which user it was from, then I would just get all the pins belong to the board/user and loop through them to see if the hashtag occurs in the note.

As JP Hellemons points out, there is no search endpoint in the Pinterest API as yet.